# How to generate report using PIVOT based on date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables MasterTableTest8 and HistoricDatatest8.

```
  create table MasterTableTest8
(ID int primary key, Name varchar(10))

insert into MasterTableTest8 values (1,'ATS')
insert into MasterTableTest8 values (2,'BTS')
 CREATE TABLE HistoricDatatest8
(
ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MasterTableTest8(ID),
Name varchar(100),
ShortName  varchar(10),
Reason varchar(10),
Importance varchar(10),
Noofissues int,
inserteddate datetime
)
insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (1,'ATS','S',   'Other','High',26,getdate()-7)
insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (1,'ATS','S',   'Other','High',8,getdate()+7)
insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (1,'ATS','S',   'Other','High',80,getdate())

insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (2,'BTS','S1',   'Other','LOW',26,getdate()-7)
insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (2,'BTS','S1',   'Other','LOW',8,getdate()+7)
insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (2,'BTS','S1',   'Other','LOW',80,getdate())
```

> --Created and inserted two tables.

```
select 
N.ID,
N.Name,
ShortName,
Reason,
Importance,
Noofissues,
inserteddate
INTO #TABLE
FROM HistoricDatatest8 N
JOIN MasterTableTest S ON N.ID=S.ID
```

> --Inserting the required data in the Hash table.

```
--drop table #table

   DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [inserteddate], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [inserteddate], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [inserteddate] FROM #TABLE) PV  
           ORDER BY [inserteddate]

           DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
          SELECT * FROM 
         ( 
             SELECT * FROM #TABLE
         ) x
         PIVOT 
         (
             count(Noofissues)
             FOR [inserteddate] IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) p'
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Current Result

[image: current results image]

Expected Result:

[image: expected results image]

Comment: You have various errors in your SQL syntax. Please correct them. Also, please add actual and expected result set to question.

Comment: @Chris Pickford, just done the changes and seems issues is with date related one, could you help out on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of R & D i got this result, might be useful to some others. if any optimized answer will be appreciated.

select * from HistoricDatatest80 order by ID
    select N.ID,N.Name,ShortName,Reason,Importance,Noofissues,inserteddate INTO #TABLE FROM HistoricDatatest80 N JOIN MasterTableTest80 S ON N.ID=S.ID

```
--drop table #table

   DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols +',','')+ '['+DATEValue+']'
           FROM    (SELECT  DISTINCT (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [inserteddate], 106)) AS DATEValue FROM HistoricDatatest80) PV  
           ORDER BY DATEValue
           print @cols
           DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
          SELECT * FROM 
         ( 
             SELECT ShortName,Reason,Importance,Noofissues,(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [inserteddate], 106)) AS DATEValue FROM #TABLE 
         ) x
         PIVOT 
         (
             sum(Noofissues)
             FOR [DATEValue] IN (' + @cols + ')

        ) p'    
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query   


   drop table #table
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your expected result? Your current display shows the same current and expected result.

Are you expecting:
Date | Name | ShortName | Reason | Importance | Number of Issues|
05-Jul-16 | ATS | S| Other| High|26
12-Jul-16|BTS |S1| Other | LOW|80

Comment: Currently all 5th july , 12th july and 19th july are showing as zero's (0)

Comment: and if i add one more row in the table for the same date i am getting compilation error                                                                                                                             (The column '12 Jul 2016' was specified multiple times for 'p'.)                                                                                                                  insert into HistoricDatatest8 values (1,'ATS','S',   'Other','Meduim',80,getdate())